# svg overlaps through other svgs - how to make SVG not being transparent?

Tags: svg

I use this SVG in the animation but you can see other SVG in the background through this car, is it because it is transparent?

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<g transform="translate(1 1)">
    <g>
        <g>
            <path d="M101.4,314.733c-9.387,0-17.067,7.68-17.067,17.067s7.68,17.067,17.067,17.067c9.387,0,17.067-7.68,17.067-17.067
                S110.787,314.733,101.4,314.733z"/>
            <path d="M408.6,314.733c-9.387,0-17.067,7.68-17.067,17.067s7.68,17.067,17.067,17.067s17.067-7.68,17.067-17.067
                S417.987,314.733,408.6,314.733z"/>
            <path d="M297.667,255H255c-5.12,0-8.533,3.413-8.533,8.533s3.413,8.533,8.533,8.533h34.133v8.533c0,5.12,3.413,8.533,8.533,8.533
                s8.533-3.413,8.533-8.533v-17.067C306.2,258.413,302.787,255,297.667,255z"/>
            <path d="M483.693,212.333H403.48l-91.307-91.307c-3.413-3.413-8.533-3.413-11.947,0s-3.413,8.533,0,11.947l79.36,79.36h-81.92
                v-25.6c0-5.12-3.413-8.533-8.533-8.533s-8.533,3.413-8.533,8.533v25.6h-59.733v-25.6c0-5.12-3.413-8.533-8.533-8.533
                c-5.12,0-8.533,3.413-8.533,8.533v25.6h-59.733V178.2c0-14.507-11.093-25.6-25.6-25.6s-25.6,11.093-25.6,25.6v34.133h-66.56
                C10.947,212.333-1,224.28-1,239.64v73.387c0,15.36,11.947,27.307,27.307,27.307h15.963c4.075,29.155,28.753,51.2,59.131,51.2
                c30.378,0,55.056-22.045,59.131-51.2h188.938c4.075,29.155,28.753,51.2,59.131,51.2s55.056-22.045,59.131-51.2h15.963
                c15.36,0,27.307-11.947,27.307-27.307V239.64C511,224.28,499.053,212.333,483.693,212.333z M109.933,178.2
                c0-5.12,3.413-8.533,8.533-8.533S127,173.08,127,178.2v34.133h-17.067V178.2z M101.4,374.467
                c-23.893,0-42.667-18.773-42.667-42.667c0-23.893,18.773-42.667,42.667-42.667c23.893,0,42.667,18.773,42.667,42.667
                C144.067,355.693,125.293,374.467,101.4,374.467z M408.6,374.467c-23.893,0-42.667-18.773-42.667-42.667
                c0-23.893,18.773-42.667,42.667-42.667c23.893,0,42.667,18.773,42.667,42.667C451.267,355.693,432.493,374.467,408.6,374.467z
                 M483.693,323.267h-15.963c-4.075-29.155-28.753-51.2-59.131-51.2c-0.138,0-0.274,0.009-0.412,0.01
                c-0.148-0.001-0.294-0.01-0.441-0.01c-29.867,0-54.613,22.187-58.88,51.2H160.531c-3.821-27.339-25.761-48.416-53.528-50.936
                c-0.203-0.019-0.409-0.029-0.613-0.046c-0.699-0.056-1.397-0.114-2.103-0.147c-0.957-0.046-1.919-0.072-2.887-0.072
                s-1.93,0.026-2.887,0.072c-0.706,0.033-1.404,0.09-2.103,0.147c-0.204,0.017-0.41,0.027-0.613,0.046
                c-27.767,2.52-49.707,23.597-53.528,50.936H26.307c-5.973,0-10.24-4.267-10.24-10.24V280.6h25.6c5.12,0,8.533-3.413,8.533-8.533
                s-3.413-8.533-8.533-8.533h-25.6V239.64c0-5.973,4.267-10.24,10.24-10.24h66.56v0h51.2v0h68.265c0,0,0.001,0,0.001,0
                s0.001,0,0.001,0h76.797c0,0,0.001,0,0.001,0s0.001,0,0.001,0h110.93c0,0,0.001,0,0.001,0s0.001,0,0.001,0h83.625
                c5.973,0,10.24,4.267,10.24,10.24v23.893h-25.6c-5.12,0-8.533,3.413-8.533,8.533s3.413,8.533,8.533,8.533h25.6v32.427
                C493.933,319,489.667,323.267,483.693,323.267z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/180002/car-transport

If I set the background color, the whole SVG will be in color, not just the car....
this is mind-boggling to me, what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to duplicate the part of the path that draws the outside shape and draw it first as an underlay with a fill of white & a fill-rule: non-zero.

```css
svg {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" >
<g transform="translate(1 1)">
    <g stroke="none" stroke-width="5">
            <path fill="white" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M109.933,178.2
                c0-5.12,3.413-8.533,8.533-8.533S127,173.08,127,178.2v34.133h-17.067V178.2z M101.4,374.467
                c-23.893,0-42.667-18.773-42.667-42.667c0-23.893,18.773-42.667,42.667-42.667c23.893,0,42.667,18.773,42.667,42.667
                C144.067,355.693,125.293,374.467,101.4,374.467z M408.6,374.467c-23.893,0-42.667-18.773-42.667-42.667
                c0-23.893,18.773-42.667,42.667-42.667c23.893,0,42.667,18.773,42.667,42.667C451.267,355.693,432.493,374.467,408.6,374.467z
                 M483.693,323.267h-15.963c-4.075-29.155-28.753-51.2-59.131-51.2c-0.138,0-0.274,0.009-0.412,0.01
                c-0.148-0.001-0.294-0.01-0.441-0.01c-29.867,0-54.613,22.187-58.88,51.2H160.531c-3.821-27.339-25.761-48.416-53.528-50.936
                c-0.203-0.019-0.409-0.029-0.613-0.046c-0.699-0.056-1.397-0.114-2.103-0.147c-0.957-0.046-1.919-0.072-2.887-0.072
                s-1.93,0.026-2.887,0.072c-0.706,0.033-1.404,0.09-2.103,0.147c-0.204,0.017-0.41,0.027-0.613,0.046
                c-27.767,2.52-49.707,23.597-53.528,50.936H26.307c-5.973,0-10.24-4.267-10.24-10.24V280.6h25.6c5.12,0,8.533-3.413,8.533-8.533
                s-3.413-8.533-8.533-8.533h-25.6V239.64c0-5.973,4.267-10.24,10.24-10.24h66.56v0h51.2v0h68.265c0,0,0.001,0,0.001,0
                s0.001,0,0.001,0h76.797c0,0,0.001,0,0.001,0s0.001,0,0.001,0h110.93c0,0,0.001,0,0.001,0s0.001,0,0.001,0h83.625
                c5.973,0,10.24,4.267,10.24,10.24v23.893h-25.6c-5.12,0-8.533,3.413-8.533,8.533s3.413,8.533,8.533,8.533h25.6v32.427
                C493.933,319,489.667,323.267,483.693,323.267z"/>
        </g>
  
  
  
            <path d="M101.4,314.733c-9.387,0-17.067,7.68-17.067,17.067s7.68,17.067,17.067,17.067c9.387,0,17.067-7.68,17.067-17.067
                S110.787,314.733,101.4,314.733z"/>
            <path d="M408.6,314.733c-9.387,0-17.067,7.68-17.067,17.067s7.68,17.067,17.067,17.067s17.067-7.68,17.067-17.067
                S417.987,314.733,408.6,314.733z"/>
            <path d="M297.667,255H255c-5.12,0-8.533,3.413-8.533,8.533s3.413,8.533,8.533,8.533h34.133v8.533c0,5.12,3.413,8.533,8.533,8.533
                s8.533-3.413,8.533-8.533v-17.067C306.2,258.413,302.787,255,297.667,255z"/>
            <path d="M483.693,212.333H403.48l-91.307-91.307c-3.413-3.413-8.533-3.413-11.947,0s-3.413,8.533,0,11.947l79.36,79.36h-81.92
                v-25.6c0-5.12-3.413-8.533-8.533-8.533s-8.533,3.413-8.533,8.533v25.6h-59.733v-25.6c0-5.12-3.413-8.533-8.533-8.533
                c-5.12,0-8.533,3.413-8.533,8.533v25.6h-59.733V178.2c0-14.507-11.093-25.6-25.6-25.6s-25.6,11.093-25.6,25.6v34.133h-66.56
                C10.947,212.333-1,224.28-1,239.64v73.387c0,15.36,11.947,27.307,27.307,27.307h15.963c4.075,29.155,28.753,51.2,59.131,51.2
                c30.378,0,55.056-22.045,59.131-51.2h188.938c4.075,29.155,28.753,51.2,59.131,51.2s55.056-22.045,59.131-51.2h15.963
                c15.36,0,27.307-11.947,27.307-27.307V239.64C511,224.28,499.053,212.333,483.693,212.333z M109.933,178.2
                c0-5.12,3.413-8.533,8.533-8.533S127,173.08,127,178.2v34.133h-17.067V178.2z M101.4,374.467
                c-23.893,0-42.667-18.773-42.667-42.667c0-23.893,18.773-42.667,42.667-42.667c23.893,0,42.667,18.773,42.667,42.667
                C144.067,355.693,125.293,374.467,101.4,374.467z M408.6,374.467c-23.893,0-42.667-18.773-42.667-42.667
                c0-23.893,18.773-42.667,42.667-42.667c23.893,0,42.667,18.773,42.667,42.667C451.267,355.693,432.493,374.467,408.6,374.467z
                 M483.693,323.267h-15.963c-4.075-29.155-28.753-51.2-59.131-51.2c-0.138,0-0.274,0.009-0.412,0.01
                c-0.148-0.001-0.294-0.01-0.441-0.01c-29.867,0-54.613,22.187-58.88,51.2H160.531c-3.821-27.339-25.761-48.416-53.528-50.936
                c-0.203-0.019-0.409-0.029-0.613-0.046c-0.699-0.056-1.397-0.114-2.103-0.147c-0.957-0.046-1.919-0.072-2.887-0.072
                s-1.93,0.026-2.887,0.072c-0.706,0.033-1.404,0.09-2.103,0.147c-0.204,0.017-0.41,0.027-0.613,0.046
                c-27.767,2.52-49.707,23.597-53.528,50.936H26.307c-5.973,0-10.24-4.267-10.24-10.24V280.6h25.6c5.12,0,8.533-3.413,8.533-8.533
                s-3.413-8.533-8.533-8.533h-25.6V239.64c0-5.973,4.267-10.24,10.24-10.24h66.56v0h51.2v0h68.265c0,0,0.001,0,0.001,0
                s0.001,0,0.001,0h76.797c0,0,0.001,0,0.001,0s0.001,0,0.001,0h110.93c0,0,0.001,0,0.001,0s0.001,0,0.001,0h83.625
                c5.973,0,10.24,4.267,10.24,10.24v23.893h-25.6c-5.12,0-8.533,3.413-8.533,8.533s3.413,8.533,8.533,8.533h25.6v32.427
                C493.933,319,489.667,323.267,483.693,323.267z"/>
        </g>



  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that image has no background; as you can see in F12 Developer tools

A background color will fill... the **whole background**

[image]

You can't paint only the car body because the SVG path doesn't allow it

Styling the path:

[image]

results in:

[image]